# Как сделать быстро меняющиеся картинки в android Drawable с обращением к ним через строку ресурсов c мета-символами?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-drawable, android-assets

Приложение для броска кубика с короткой анимацией, собственно, самого броска. Я сделал 100 JPG-изображений для каждого из 20-ти возможных результатов (кубик 20-гранный). Сначала пытался менять изображения в Drawable в цикле через обращение напрямую к ресурсам (.setImageResource), но для этого нужно четко задавать конкретное имя нужного файла, без использования мета-символов, а я не могу заранее знать, что выпадет на кубике (Random()). Поэтому решил использовать Assets. С ними приложение отрабатывает без видимых ошибок, цикл проходится верно, но изображения в Drawable по факту не меняются, только в самом конце, когда событие уже закончилось, выставляется нужная последняя картинка, причем размером меньше, чем она должна быть.

Укажите, пожалуйста, на мою ошибку.

Все файлы изображений я проименовал так: d20+выпавший номер (из 20)+кадр анимации (из 100). Например, d2007050 - 50ый кадр анимации броска кубика, когда выпадет семерка. Вот полный код:

```
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
public Random random = new Random();


public void Throw(View view) throws InterruptedException {
    ImageView dice = findViewById(R.id.imageD20);
    dice.setImageResource(R.drawable.d2002030);
    int result = random.nextInt(19); // throwing dice...
    long startTime = 0;
    long delayTime = 0;
    String fileNameStr = new String();


    for (int i = 0; i<=100; i++) {       // animation
        fileNameStr = getResources().getString(R.string.fileName, result, i + 1);
       InputStream img = null;
       AssetManager mngr = this.getAssets();
        try {
           InputStream ims = getAssets().open(fileNameStr);
           Drawable image = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
           dice.setImageDrawable(image);
                      }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        delayTime = startTime+10;
        while(System.currentTimeMillis() < delayTime);
   }


}
}
```

А вот ресурсы, откуда я беру строку с именем файла:

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">D20dice</string>
<string name="fileName">""d20%1$02d%2$03d".jpg"</string>
</resources>
```

Нашел как сделать без assets, просто через ресурсы - getResources().getIdentifier() позволяет найти идентификатор ресурса через строковую переменную. Код Throw поменял следующим образом:

```
 public void Throw(View view) throws InterruptedException {
    ImageView dice = findViewById(R.id.imageD20);
    dice.setImageResource(R.drawable.d2002030);
    int result = random.nextInt(19); // throwing dice...
    long startTime = 0;
    long delayTime = 0;
    String fileNameStr = new String();
    int resID;

    for (int i = 0; i<=100; i++) {       // animation

        fileNameStr = getResources().getString(R.string.fileName, result, i + 1);

        resID = getResources().getIdentifier(fileNameStr , "drawable", getPackageName());

        dice.setImageResource(resID);
        dice.invalidate();
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        delayTime = startTime+10;
        while(System.currentTimeMillis() < delayTime);
    }

}
```

Теперь начальная и конечная картинки анимации выдаются в верном размере, но все промежуточные кадры все также не показываются.

Попробовал через AnimationDrawable: теперь при первом броске опять только первый и последний кадр, при повторном броске программа вылетает. Привожу этот вариант кода ниже:

```
 public void Throw(View view) throws InterruptedException {
    ImageView dice = findViewById(R.id.imageD20);
    dice.setImageResource(R.drawable.d2002030);
    int result = random.nextInt(19); // throwing dice...
    String fileNameStr = new String();
    Drawable frame;
    AnimationDrawable diceAnimation = new AnimationDrawable();
    diceAnimation.setOneShot(true);

    int resID;

    for (int i = 0; i<=100; i++) {       // animation

        fileNameStr = getResources().getString(R.string.fileName, result, i + 1);

        resID = getResources().getIdentifier(fileNameStr , "drawable", getPackageName());
        frame = getResources().getDrawable(resID);
        diceAnimation.addFrame(frame, 200);
         }


    dice.setBackground(diceAnimation);
    diceAnimation.start();


}
```

Comment: Попробуйте после dice.setImageDrawable(image); dice.invalidate();

Comment: Спасибо, но с invalidate() ничего не меняется, все то же самое

Comment: Попробуйте AnimationDrawable. Можно через xml или программно. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149487/animationdrawable-programmatically-without-animation-list-xml/10151505

Comment: Как раз вот тоже дошел до этого! И код получился, в принципе, как по Вашей ссылке, но почему-то опять не работает анимация. Сейчас добавлю код в основной вопрос.

Comment: я протестировал - у вас форматная строка неправильная - нужно без расширения и можно без кавычек d20%1$02d%2$03d . У меня все работает.

Comment: Да, строку я поменял, когда отказался от assets (они только так работали), забыл упомянуть. В общем до момента diceAnimation.start(); все идет хорошо, я проверил состав diceAnimation после заполнения в цикле с помощью  нескольких getFrame - картинки хранятся верные. Но анимация не показывается. Я подумал, может дело в sdk - переустановил все и пересобрал заново, подключил эмулятор и проверил на нем - то же самое. Заменил getResources().getDrawable(resID); на ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), resID, null);, т.к. первый вариант, вроде как, устарел. Но изменений нет.

Comment: Сейчас увидел в логах после запуска следующее:      I/Choreographer: Skipped 83 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 140MB to 128MB  -  может быть, проблема в самих файлах картинок? Это jpg 320x240, размером по 31 кб

Comment: это небольшие размеры, нужно смотреть весь код, я на реальном устройстве тестировал, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678593/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread

Comment: Да, я поэкспериментировал с drawable-xxxhdpi и drawable-nodpi - никаких изменений. А как можно предоставить весь код? Думаю, нужно прямо с картинками. Весь проект через файлообменник?

Comment: @Style-7, вот весь код с ресурсами: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qjJgilFbP70MYFEiCrDDg6GEBa2s647n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема, похоже, была в том, что изначально фон я ставил с помощью setImageResource, а потом подгружал анимацию в бэкграунд (setBackground(diceAnimation)).
В любом случае, анимация заработала с большой задержкой перед началом - для AnimationDrawble 100 кадров 320x240 - это, похоже, перебор. Решил проблему преобразовав все анимации в GIF и выводом их через подключенную android-gif-drawable:
https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable